# Yellow background for revision's description except initial in the iOS app

Tags: support, ios-app

In the iOS app's revisions page all revisions except initial have yellow background for description:

> [image: revisions]

What is the reason to make them different?

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be removed in 1.6.7.1.

There are two types of revisions "single_user" which corresponds to an edit, and "vote_based" which corresponds to events like bounties, being featured on Twitter, etc.

When this view was designed 3 years ago, the web had a yellow backgrounds for "single_user" which is why the app does.  At some point the web got rid of it but I never noticed.  As for why there's no background on the initial revision, that's because there's no comment and it looked weird in the app so I gave it one, and I felt white was the most appropriate.

I'm getting rid of it now.